# Case distinction in a proof using beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I have the following problem: For a proof of a theorem I need a case distinction inside a proof environment of a beamer presentation. I think that an enumerate might be helpful, the problem is however that I want some enumitems other than (a),(b),(c). I tried to set this using `\setbeamertemplate`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\arabic{enumi}. Fall:}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item asd
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the whole thing looks really crappy, because the enumitem is right justified and there is not enough space to accommodate this *longer* string. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this, or how to make a nice-looking case distinction for a beamer document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to use a slightly modified `description` environment and an auxiliary counter; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}

\newcounter{count}
\newcommand\mycount{\stepcounter{count}\thecount. }
\resetcounteronoverlays{count}

\setbeamersize{description width=2.5cm}
\setbeamertemplate{description item}{\mycount\insertdescriptionitem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{description}
      \item[Winter:] asd
      \item[Spring:] asd
      \item[Summer:] asd
      \item[Fall:] asd
    \end{description}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, with left alignment for the labels:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}

\newcounter{count}
\newcommand\mycount{\stepcounter{count}\thecount. }
\resetcounteronoverlays{count}


\setbeamersize{description width=2.5cm}
\setbeamertemplate{description item}{%
  \makebox[2cm][l]{\mycount\insertdescriptionitem\hfill}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{description}
      \item[Winter:] asd
      \item[Spring:] asd
      \item[Summer:] asd
      \item[Fall:] asd
    \end{description}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work quite nicely. On a different subject, the word _Fall_ in this context is german for case and has nothing to do with seasons :)

Comment: @hfhc2 sorry about the misunderstanding ;-) My German knowledge reduces to a few words (and Fall was not one of them); on the bright side, now I can add a new word to my list.